# WxPython windows does not popup

Tags: python, wxpython

I've written the following snippet to display a simple window.

It however neither does show the window nor reports any error:

```
import wx    
class myFrame (wx.App) :
        def __init__(self):
            x = wx.Frame.__init__(self, "", size=(200,200), title="Thanks", style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU |  wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLOSE)
            x.Show(True)

    frm = wx.App(False)
    things = myFrame
    frm.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some  few problems in your code.
You may want to start from the following code:

```
import wx

class myFrame (wx.Frame):         #inherits from a Frame not from an Application
      def __init__(self, parent):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(200,200), title="Thanks")
          # Note the order of the three positional arguments above
          # Second one is the parent frame (None here) and the third the window ID


frm = wx.App(False)
things = myFrame(None)           # you must call the class to create an instance
things.Show()                    # this is the correct position to show it
frm.MainLoop()
```

If you run the code you get an empty frame. From here you can try different styles if you want.